# checkedout document error "This element is not available. Possibly deleted by another user"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, error, check-out

I have a list item id of the document library checked out document and when I get the list item like this:

```
SPListItem item = list.GetItemByIdSelectedFields(Convert.ToInt32(itemID, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), new string[] { Constants.ID });
```

I am getting an error:

> "This element is not available. Possibly deleted by another user".

What is that I am doing wrong here? Checked out document or not checked in document will also have id?

Comment: Are you sure this is the error message? I have only seen the error "item is not exist".And what is the value of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture？

Comment: Yes Item is not exist. May be deleted by another user is the error.  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture we have 2 language and the value depends on the current browser language.

Comment: sorry "Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user " is the error.